# Prove that if $x | (3x + 20)$ then the only positive $x$ for which the statement is true are $1,2,4,5,10,20$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

How can I give a valid proof to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x$ divides $3x$ since $x$ divides $x$. Now $3x$ and $20$ are in addition.

For $3x+20$ to be divisible by $x$, $(3x+20)/x$ should give an integer value (Problem Statement).

Now let us assume, for a moment, that $x$ doesn't divide $20$. This means that $20/x$ would give a non-integral value. Say this value is $p$. Now $(3x+20)/x = (3x)/x + 20/x = 3 + p$. From our assumption, since p is non-integral, $3+p$ should also be non-integral. But this is a contradiction from the statement of the question. Hence, our assumption was wrong and therefore $p$ is integral. Hence $20$ should be divisible by $x$ and therefore possible values of $x$ are $1,2,4,5,10,20$.

Comment: Hello @Ranveer, I am just wondering what law/theorem are you using to justify that "x must also divide 20 since it divides 3x."

Comment: @Giovanni is it better now?

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

For some integer $n$ we have $nx = 3x + 20$, and it follows that $(n-3)x = 20$. The $x$ that satisfy this are precisely the divisors of $20$: $1,2,4,5,10,20$.